# How can I auto-create .docker folder in the home directory when spinning up VM Cluster (gce_vm_cluster) on gcloud through R?

Tags: r, docker, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I create VMs using the following command in R:

```
vms <- gce_vm_cluster(vm_prefix=vm_base_name,
                      cluster_size=cluster_size,
                      docker_image = my_docker,
                      ssh_args = list(username="test_user",
                      key.pub="/home/test_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub", 
                      key.private="/home/test_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine"),
                      predefined_type = "n1-highmem-2")
```

now when I SSH into the VMs, I do not find the .docker folder in the home directory

```
test_user@test_server_name:~$ gcloud beta compute --project "my_test_project" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "r-vm3"
test_user@r-vm3 ~ $ ls -a
.  ..  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .ssh
```

Now the below command gives an error (..obviously)

```
test_user@r-vm3 ~ $ docker pull gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1' locally
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.
```

I need to run the `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` command to get the folder/file `.docker/config.json`

```
test_user@r-vm3 ~ $ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
/home/test_user/.docker/config.json configured to use this credential helper for GCR registries
test_user@r-vm3 ~ $ ls -a
.  ..  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .docker  .ssh
```

Now,

```
test_user@r-vm3 ~ $ docker pull gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1
version1: Pulling from my_test_project/myimage
Digest: sha256:98abc76543d2e10987f6ghi5j4321098k7654321l0987m65no4321p09qrs87654t
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1
gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1
```

**What I am trying to resolve**:
I need the .docker/config.json to appear in the VMs without SSHing in and running the `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` command

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a bash script, upload to a cloud storage bucket, and call it while creating the cluster? Also you mentioned "R" Are you talking about R script?